# How long does it take for a refrigerator to recover after being turned off?

Tags: repair, appliances

I turned mom's fridge down to 0 so I could sleep in the living room without hearing the sound cycling all night.  Unfortunately, I forgot to turn it back on so I just talked her through turning the knob back to 5.  How long will it take to get the fridge to power back up?

Comment: Did you check if the fridge has power ? any lights on  like open the door and is the light on ?

Comment: Assuming the light is on - proving power to fridge - a shake or knock may well bring it back to life. There may be a relay that's decided to take a break. How long was it turned off for?

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify your question. You _seem_ to be asking whether the fridge should turn on immediately after having the dial turned back "up". If that's your actual question (I think it is), the answer is yes, it should turn on immediately and if it doesn't, something's wrong with it.

Comment: This is a _usage_ question and therefore off topic.

Comment: A fridge with a rotary knob thermostat will likely turn on almost immediately once you "click" past the temperature setpoint.  If it doesn't, something has failed.  If you broke your mom's fridge, she's going to stop letting you crash on the couch.

Comment: Next time I recommend earplugs. And/or learning to live with it.

Answer (score 4):

Since some people don't like that I am answering the important but *unasked* question, here is the direct answer to the original question, which itself is ambiguous:

- How long will it take to get the fridge to power back up?

Well, if it was truly off - i.e., if "0" == **OFF** and not *lowest 'on' setting* - then it should take no more than about 5 seconds for the refrigerator to power up and decide that the compressor needs to run. If it was simply on the lowest setting (i.e., least effective, which is highest temperature) then it was never truly "off" and there is no "on", just "get to a better temperature".

- **IMPLIED:** How long will it take to get back to a normal temperature?

Anywhere from 1 to several hours, possibly an entire day. It depends on the current temperature of the refrigerator interior, which in turn depends on the room temperature and the amount of time the refrigerator was off and how well insulated it is and the current status of the gaskets, plus how efficient the refrigerator is at cooling. Too many variables to guess beyond "1 to several hours".

---

But what I really *still* want to concentrate on is an important message about **food safety**:

Refrigerators, when working properly, are generally fairly consistent, but the actual temperature will vary a lot due to manufacturing and component differences. That is why, until recently, most refrigerators didn't show an actual temperature but instead use a number (e.g., 0 - 10). 5 might be 40 degrees on one refrigerator and on another (same model!) it might be 38 or 42. 0 might be 42 (just a little high) or 48 (way too high).

Proper temperature for a refrigerator is anywhere between 32F and 40F, and for a freezer ideally around 0F. After one round of problems, I got some great little remote thermometers. One goes in the refrigerator, one in the freezer. Big LCD display goes on the door - and works from quite a distance so I actually have the displays for both kitchen and basement on the outside of the basement refrigerator. The ones I got are [these AcuRite thermometers](https://amzn.to/3nrI45F) but there are others available:

[image: themrmometers]

These also keep a daily min. and max., which is great if there is a temporary problem (e.g., "0" oops, or a short power outage) and you are not able to monitor the temperature at the time.

The big problem with a refrigerator and food safety is that if the refrigerator is turned off or just warmer than normal ("0" setting for a day), some food will be fine (e.g., juice, wine, many fruits and vegetables), some will spoil faster than usual but be obvious (smell or appearance) and *some will spoil without being obviously spoiled*. That is dangerous, particularly with elderly people.

So be careful in general, and if this is going to be done on any regular basis, investing in a decent thermometer can really help with peace of mind.

Answer (score 1):

The refrigerator should have started running again within seconds of moving the knob back to "5".  If it didn't do that, the thermostat may be broken - they often aren't turned for 20 years, and when they are turned, they break.   If the refrigerator light works when you open the door, it's not a tripped GFCI or breaker.

When you turned the knob back to 5 and it started running, that means the fridge is "turned on".  I think you're asking how long it'll take to return to normal.

A fridge/freezer can have hundreds of dollars of food in it.  if the responsible person is angry at you, they are entirely correct, so take your licking and apologize.  You are very in the wrong here.

In the future when you have that problem, turn on a white-noise generator like a fan to mask the sound.

Once it is restarted, the fridge will run continuously until it reaches operating temperature.   Since you claim the sound is unctious when it runs, you should be able to tell when it cuts off.  I would expect an hour or two.  Depends how much food is in it, and how warm it got.

I hope your mother checked the temperature of the food in the fridge at the time of detection.  If it's still pretty cool it may be ok. The warmer it got, the faster bacteria grew.  It should be cooked with extra care and not used raw. Salad lettuce can probably be washed.  Things like milk in open containers should be tossed out if they were found warm.

Anything that was frozen and thawed should be moved to the fridge and eaten soon. Food once frozen and thawed should not be frozen again.

Comment: While this may save mother's life it doesn't help turn that fridge back on!

Comment: This answer the questions of "am I responsible for the ire of the fridge's owner", "is the food safe to eat", "what should I do with previously frozen food", and "roughly how long will it take for the fridge to get cold again". It does _not_ answer what appears to be the OP's actual question, "how long will it take to _turn on_ after being unplugged?"

Comment: @Tim Oh, I missed that!  Wait, no I didn't. The question title is clear - oh wait, someone edited that.   I am now very confused.

Comment: @Tim I can't tell. I'm adding a new paragraph 1 to cover that.

Comment: @FreeMan I can't determine OP's intent and they haven't been back. I'm adding a new paragraph 1 to cover the eventuality that it didn't restart.

Comment: Sadly. nobody really knows the OP's intent and he hasn't come back to clarify. Oh well... moving on.